# Incrementing a character in Java explanation

Tags: java, character, character-properties

I have a Java fragment that looks like this:

```
    char ch = 'A';
    System.out.println("ch = " + ch);
```

which prints: **A**

then when I do this

```
    ch++; // increment ch
    System.out.println("ch =" + ch);
```

it now prints: **B**

I also tried it with `Z` and resulted to a `[` *(open square brace)* 
and with `-` and resulted to `.`

---

How did this happen? What can be the possible explanation for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For characters 0 to 127, you follow the ASCII character set.

[image]

As you can see the character after (90) `Z` is (91) `[` and the character after (45) `-` is (46) `.`

Try

```
char ch = '-';
ch += '-'; // == (char) 90 or 'Z'
```

or even more bizarre

```
char ch = '0';
ch *= 1.15; // == (char) 48 * 1.15 = 54 or '6'
```

Comment: so when I incremented `ch` what value did it increment? is it the `dec, Hx, `or `Oct`?

Comment: @Þaw Actually it is none of them.  A char is a 16-bit binary value i.e. it has 16 bits.  You can display this as a `char` as you have seen or as decimal, or hex, of octal, but really it is just a collection of bits.

Comment: wow! I tried what you did sir and it worked, amazing HAHA. sorry for being ignorant :D still learning a lot.

Comment: @Þaw Try the one I just added ;) '0' * 1.15 => '6'

Comment: Sir I tried it it went to 7, Sir I've an additional question what is `'\u0000'` ?

Comment: @Þaw It is just character 0, or the "nul" character. You can also write `'\0'`

Answer (score 3):

This happens because a 'char' is essentially a number, in Unicode format in which each character you type is represented by a number. This means that a character can be treated just like a number in that one can be added subtracted or anything else.

For more information on the specific mappings try [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The `char` data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of  '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive). Arithmetic operations can be performed on `char` literals because they are actually numeric values representing the Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

it is actually incrementing the ascii values. A s value is 65 so 66 is B. Again Z's value is 90 and [ is 91

Answer (score 1):

`Char` has an numerical representation of characters. If you try to cast it to `int` like `int a = (int) 'A';` you'll get the char code. When you increment the `char` value, you'll move down in `ASCII table`, and get the next table value.